# Gulp.js Watch not picking up changes in SASS

Tags: gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

My gulp runs with no errors, but does not pick up any changes to the SASS. If I stop gulp and re-run, it compiles the sass fine. Here is my gulp file.

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
gutil = require('gulp-util'),
browserify = require('gulp-browserify'),
concat = require('gulp-concat');
gulpif = require('gulp-if');
uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
bower = require('gulp-bower');
sass = require('gulp-sass');
imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
pngcrush = require('imagemin-pngcrush');
livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
// Create gulp plugins from node install
// npm install --save-dev gulp-**
var jsSources,
sassSources,
outputDir,
sassStyle
// Create variables for enviroments
env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
if (env==='development') {
outputDir = './';
sassStyle = 'expanded';
} else {
outputDir = './';
sassStyle = 'compressed';
}
// Conditions for development and production enviroments
jsSources = ['js/*.js'];
sassSources = ['scss/style.scss'];
imageSources = ['images/**/*.*'];
bowerDir = ['bower_components/'];
// Paths to files
gulp.task('js', function() {
gulp.src(jsSources)
.pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
.pipe(browserify())
.pipe(gulpif (env === 'production', uglify()))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
});
// Concat all javascript files
gulp.task('images', function() {
gulp.src(imageSources)
.pipe(gulpif (env === 'production', imagemin({
progressive: true,
svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
use: [pngcrush()]
})))
.pipe(gulpif (env === 'production', gulp.dest(outputDir + 'images')))
});
// Compress all images
gulp.task('css', function() {
gulp.src(sassSources)
.on('error', function(error) {
console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
})
.pipe(sass({outputStyle: sassStyle})
.on('error', sass.logError)
)
.pipe(gulp.dest(outputDir));
});
gulp.task('watch', function() {
livereload.listen()
gulp.watch(jsSources, ['js']);
gulp.watch(imageSources, ['images']);
gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', ['css']);
});
// Watch task, looks for changes and automatically updates.
gulp.task('default', ['js', 'css', 'images', 'watch']);
// Runs all tasks
```

Can anyone see anything that would cause this issue for me?

Comment: why are you using `'scss/*.scss'` instead of `sassSources` on your watch? although it should work either way

Comment: I want to watch for any change to any file in the scss folder but just pipe in style.scss for the task of that makes sense

Comment: Just tried it locally, it seems to work on a minimal version - just the SASS/CSS and watch part - can you post your package.json to check on versions?

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^3.1.1",
    "gulp-bower": "0.0.13",
    "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "imagemin-pngcrush": "^5.1.0",
    "reset-css": "^2.2.0",
    "sass-module-importer": "^1.4.0",
    "wordpress-core-css": "github:DesignImage/wordpress-core-css"
  }
}

Comment: works locally for simple files - maybe you can extract this yourself from the project and just try in a simpler context; i assume the problem is related to your environment or other things not mentioned in the question

Comment: Its running in a Xamp environment, ill try and simplify it, thanks